# CSS position fixed problem with clippath or image mask only on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to background attachment fixed.
I can get the result I want with `clip-path` or `-webkit-mask-image`, however on Chrome sometimes the fixed image gets hide when its out of the view and when I'm scrolling back, it does not show up until I select something or change the browser width. I have tested this on Firefox and Edge and they were both okay.

I want to know what is the issue and is there way to fix that.

[gif issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LECeE.gif)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Issue</title>
        <style>
            .parent {
                position: relative;
                width: 500px;
                height: 200px;
                background: lightcoral;
                clip-path: inset(0);
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            .child {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/800/400");
            }

            .filler {
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 2000px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <span class="child"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="filler"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as using `position: fixed` on your child element, you also need to apply `background-attachment: fixed`. Both these styles are required.

Comment: Actually the whole point of using clip path or mask image or all other methods with using position: fixed is to not use background-attachment: fixed because of its huge performance impact while having a heavy content. Also I think that is not proper to use position: fixed with background-attachment: fixed at the same time because background-attachment will overwrite the position fixed property behavior.

Comment: Understood @miniOp, that's not a solution then.

Answer (score 0):

I went through a painful process of trying to get `clip:rect` working a few months ago, with the same issue as you're experiencing (I understand you're not using `clip:rect`). The underlying issue was that, when reloading the page, if the `clip:rect` area was not currently within view, the contents within it would not be rendered.

Resizing my screen or turning a style off and back on in the developer panel would re-render my images correctly but was not a solution, just evidence of the issue.

The solution, for me, with `clip:rect`, was in the use of the `position` style on the **contents** within the `clip:rect` element. I was initially using `relative` positioning but it needed to be `fixed` or `absolute`.

Please check what positioning you're using and see if this helps.

On an additional note - and very frustrating one too - the browser which I tested this on at the time was Chrome, mobile and desktop. I had it working very well once I'd completed development and tested it thoroughly. Today, ironically, the only browser which is not working with my `clip:rect` content is desktop Chrome!

This must have been a recent update to desktop Chrome... back to the drawing board.

Comment: First of all thank you for actually understanding the issue.
I checked my code but I don't have any other children beside the fixed position element within the clip-path not even any pesudo elements.
I even tried to make a jsfiddle but I'm not sure if its for the previewer or anything else but everything seams fine there and I cant simulate the situation